# animating GIF on draggable(): jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking to utilize jQuery's UI plugin to create draggable() and droppable() behavior similar to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yM9s5/4/). The only difference; I would like the shopping cart to play through an animation when draggable() is activated to make it more obvious to the user where they can drop their items.

However, the animation I require can not be accomplished via CSS, it is an animation of the image itself. I have both a GIF of the animation and also the equivalent sequence of JPEGs, whichever works best. What's the most elegant way to accomplish this?

*FYI: The code is sourced from an [IBM developerWorks article by Michael Abernethy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jquery5/index.html)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a callback for the [draggable's](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start) `start` event to change the `src` attribute of your cart image and then a `stop` callback to change it back.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yM9s5/6/

Another approach is this:

1. Replace your `<img>` drop target with a `<div>`.
2. Size the `<div>` through CSS to match the `<img>`.
3. Add a background image to the `<div>` to match the visual effect of the `<img>`.
4. Add a `background-image` to your `border` class and set that image to your animated GIF.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yM9s5/5/

That should work with an animated GIF but I don't have one handy to check.

Comment: For your first method - as I mentioned, I need to play through a _sequence_ of images, this is the kicker...Flipping from one to another is easily accomplished. Your second method is similar in that when using an image not in the GIF format, it is the transition from only one image to another. It does not meet the needs of N number of images. Secondly, when a GIF is used as the background image of the div, it will play through the GIF in perpetuity. I require it to play **only once** and end on the last frame. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jordan: Use an animated GIF that has its "play once" flag turned on. You should be able to convert your sequence of images to a single animated GIF without too much difficulty so you only need one image.

Comment: I did not know that GIFs could have a "play once" flag enabled. I was able to create a non-looping GIF in Photoshop by following [a youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXW2vlNu5Rs). Having a mouseover() fire the animation was as simple as an attr("src") swap. Thank you.

Comment: @Jordan: I had to check the flag to make sure I was remembering the right thing, found the same video :)